# How to change scala for each loop to java for each loop

Tags: java, scala

This code is used to Authenticate user by role using spring framework..

Here the scala code is change to java because of special condition

```
val authentication: Authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
     .getAuthentication();

var flag = false;
authentication.getAuthorities().foreach(authority =>
  if (authority.getAuthority().equals(role)) {
    flag = true
});
```

i tried this but it's not completed.

```
public final Authentication authentication;
authentication=SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
boolean flag=true;
authentication.getAuthorities();
for(Object authority:authentication){
    if (authority.getAuthority().equals(role)) {
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

I really tried but it's not working . if you know about this please share here.

Comment: your java code shouldn't even compile. (Spring security) `Authentication` isn't `Iterable` and you are trying to iterate it.

Comment: In the Java version I think it should say `boolean flag = false;` as well.

Comment: (side comment) why change the code to java? What is the 'special condition' that requires that?  BTW, the Scala version should be something like: `val containsRole = authentication.getAuthorities().exists(authority => authority == role)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what type `authentication.getAuthorities()` is, here is what it could look like:

```
public final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
boolean flag = false;

for (Authority authority: authentication.getAuthorities()) {
    if (authority.getAuthority().equals(role)) flag = true;
}
```